# WP Не могу войти в админку

Tags: php, wordpress

Вообщем, регистрируюсь на сайте и выдаю админку таким путём:

```
pr_capabilities a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}
```

Сначала все работает, но если выходишь из аккаунта и снова пытаешься зайти - вылазит ошибка пароля, убираю админку - опять все работает. Что это может быть?

Comment: Сбросьте куки...

Comment: Я уже и с инкогнито заходил, и с другого браузера, и с другого устройства.

Comment: Если нового админа создать - тоже самое? Может плагины какие стоят? Попробуйте по-одному отключать по очереди и тестируйте. Может в ВП самом что-то кешируется.

А ещё есть табличка usermeta. 

$wp_usermeta = $table_prefix.'usermeta';
$wp_user_level = $table_prefix.'user_level';
"INSERT INTO `$DB_NAME`.`$wp_usermeta` (`umeta_id`, `user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (NULL, '123123', '$wp_user_level', '10');";

Comment: все это стоит у меня.. Вообще не помогает, даже отключал плагины.